# unity "NullCheck" hold on to memory

Tags: unity-game-engine, null-check, il2cpp

"Null-Check" hold on to lots of memory.  why? what happened? Anybody encounter the problem?

[Null-Check hold on to memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGNp0.jpg)

Comment: Use the profile and enable deep profiler. It will show you what line of code is causing the problem. Please post that code here. No one can help without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Null check while using IL2CPP with the `Il2CppSetOptions` attribute in every function.

```
[Il2CppSetOption(Option.NullChecks, false)]
void functionName(){

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Finally, I solved it. The cause of the problem is   allocated memory by other thread, but not the main thread. I use static memory instead of dynamic allocation. And  It works well now...  ( ╯□╰ )sorry for my poor English.

Comment: @weizhong Ok, I see.